# Copying strings into an array?

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define STRING_LENGTH 20
#define MAX 30

int read_string(char string[], int n);

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    char *name_list[MAX];
    char word[STRING_LENGTH + 1];

    for (;; i++){
        printf("Enter a word.\n");
        read_string(word, STRING_LENGTH);
        if (word[i] == '\0')
            break;
        name_list[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
        strcat(name_list[i], word);

    }


}

int read_string(char string[], int n){
    int ch, i = 0;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')

    if (i < n)
        string[i++] = ch;
    string[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}
```

The point of this program is to read in words and place them into an array of pointers for sorting. this is what i have so far, my debugger is saying that the use of strcat is unsafe but I do not know why. It says to use strcat_s but that crashes my program. Any help on how to get this working?

Comment: sorry i forgot to add that if the user enters nothing after the prompt the program ends.

Comment: i fixed that but the debugger still says that the use of strcat, strcpy, and strcat_s, strcpy_s is unsafe

Comment: Also, the for loop as it is now is infinite. You should change it to `for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)`

Comment: once the user presses enter without entering a word, the loop breaks.

Comment: @moffeltje This is C; you wish you would get an IndexOutOfBounds error, instead you get far worse things.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I know but I used this Java term to explain that the program would crash. Better to say: your program would probably crash due to an index being out of bounds. (`name_list[20]`)

Comment: @moffeltje There's no guarantee that it will crash; undefined behavior is undefined. Saying that 'you get an indexoutofbound error' is IMO misleading, especially when someone new to C realizes that their program magically still works or breaks at random places when they access arrays out of bounds.

Comment: @Flower  Do you know how many words you want to enter because `if (word[i] == '\0')`  at this point as `word[I]=='\0' ` it will come out of your loop. For example - if you enter just "a" in second iteration of `while loop` then as `word[2]=='\0'` then it will just come out of  loop.

Comment: When calling `strcat`, you are passing a non-necessarily-null-terminated string as the first input parameter. That by itself yields undefined behavior. Set `name_list[i][0] == '\0'` beforehand, or better yet - simply use `strcpy`.

Comment: Don't ever `strcat()` to an unintialised "string". Here you want to use `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I tested your code and I came to the following final code that is working for me and does not give me a warning when compiled with `-Wall`.

Since you are using `strcat` instead of `strcpy`, the string stored in `words` gets added to the data in the array `name_list`. But because you didn't put all values in that array to `0`, it could happen some garbage data is stored in `name_list[i]` and the words string gets concatenated after that garbage data.

Therefore I used [`calloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc) so all values in the memory you allocate are zero. Another way is to just keep `malloc` but then change `strcat()` in `strcpy()`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define STRING_LENGTH 20
#define MAX 30

int read_string(char string[], int n);

int main(){
    int i;
    char *name_list[MAX];
    char word[STRING_LENGTH + 1];

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        printf("\nEnter a word.\n");
        read_string(word, STRING_LENGTH);
        printf("\nword%d=%s", i, word);
        if (strcmp(word, "") == 0)
            break;
        name_list[i] = calloc(STRING_LENGTH + 1, 1);
        strcat(name_list[i], word);
        printf("\nname_list[%d] = %s", i, name_list[i]);

    }
    return 0;

}

int read_string(char string[], int n){
    int ch, i = 0;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')

    if (i < n)
        string[i++] = ch;
    string[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}
```

Comment: thankyou so much,although i still get the warning message, the program doesnt crash

Comment: when i print the name list array though  get a bunch of odd charaters and not the words

Comment: Other possible issues aside, it seems like the `calloc()` call should be `calloc(STRING_LENGTH + 1, 1)`.  To avoid off-by-one problems like this, I suggest perhaps using `strdup()` instead of an allocate/copy set of operations on strings.

Comment: actually the code is fine but i am actually required to use malloc not calloc

Answer (score 1):

Use the **memcpy()** function :

```
void *memcpy(void *str1, const void *str2, size_t n)
```

or the **strcpy()** function :

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
```